# Continuous function on discrete values.

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity

> If $$\mathbb{A}=\left\{ \dfrac 1n \mid n\in \mathbb N \right \}$$ Then prove that any function $f:\mathbb{A}\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

I know the two definitions of continuity: the sequence definition and the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition.

I can also prove that any such function from a set of integer points to $\mathbb R$ is continuous, putting $\delta=\frac 12$ in the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition and using the fact that difference between two integers in at least $1$.

However, I am stuck with the question above. I don't see any *obvious* choice of $\epsilon$-$\delta$ which will help me write a proof.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I assume you mean putting $\delta = 1/2$ in the definition -- you cannot choose $\varepsilon$ to be 1/2 and say the proof is done.

Comment: @Nitin, edited,

Comment: The idea behind continuity is that if you restrict your $x$ values close enough to the point of interest, the $y$ values get close to the function value at that point. In this case, though, the domain is a bunch of discrete points. For each of them, you can restrict your attention close enough that the only point available is the point of interest, so there is only one $y$ value, which is the function value. So any function will be continuous. This is the essence of the solutions that have been given.

Comment: Adding to what @PaulSinclair said, The term for such situations: When if there an ‘if p, then q’statement. But p doesn’t even occur and thus the conditional statement isn’t “entered into” logically is known as to be “**Vacuously True**”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $x_0 \in \mathbb A$, and let $\varepsilon > 0$. We want to find $\delta > 0$ so that for all $x \in \mathbb A$ such that $|x - x_0| < \delta$, we have $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \varepsilon$. We have no information about $f$, so our only hope is to make the statement vacuously true; that is, we must find $\delta$ such that there is no $x \in \mathbb A$ in a $\delta$-neighborhood of $x_0$. We know $x_0 = \frac{1}{n}$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$. It's easy to check that $\frac{1}{n}$ is closer to $\frac{1}{n+1}$ than it is to $\frac{1}{n-1}$, so we can let $\delta = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)$.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? I am missing the point.

Comment: Try with $x_0 = 1/5$. We want to find a $\delta$ neighborhood of 1/5 with no natural reciprocals. The closest reciprocal to 1/5 is 1/6, so any delta neighborhood containing reciprocals *must* contain 1/6 as well. Thus we can shrink the neighborhood to not include 1/6 and we will be done. This is done by taking the difference between 1/5 and 1/6, and halving it for good measure (not necessary, but emphasizes the point).

Comment: So essentially, you mean that any sequence converging to some $x_o$ becomes eventually constant $(=x_o)$, since we cannot find any $x_n$ in our smartly chosen $\delta$ interval. Did I get it right? And thus the function is continuous as all $f$ values become $f(x_o)$.

Comment: The point is that the only point in that neighborhood of the point $x_0$ is the point $x_0$ .

Answer (score 1):

For any $f:A \to R :$ For any $x=1/n \in A$,  let $\epsilon =\frac {1}{n(n+1)}.$ Now for ANY $\delta >0$ we have  $ ( y \in A $ and $|y-x|< \epsilon ) \implies |f(y)-f(x)|<\delta $ because  $(y \in A $ and $ |y-x|<\epsilon)$ implies $y=x$. So $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Answer (score 0):

For any $f:A \to R :$ For $x=1/n \in A$,  let $\epsilon =\frac {1}{n(n+1)}.$ Now for ANY $\delta >0$ we have  $ ( y \in A $ and $|y-x|< \epsilon ) \implies |f(y)-f(x)|<\delta $ because  $(y \in A $ and $ |y-x|<\epsilon)$ implies $y=x$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be any given number.  Now let $x=a$ be any domain point i.e. $x\in\mathbb{A}$ which is clearly not a limit point of the domain($\mathbb{A}$) and hence by definition of limit point there is some $\delta>0$ such that the interval $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ contains no point of the domain except $x=a$. Therefore   whenever $|x-a|<\delta$ and $x\in\mathbb{A}$ then, it is trivially $|f(x)-f(a)|=0<\epsilon$ i.e. function $f$ is continuous at each point of the domain or $f$ is a continuous on $\mathbb{A}.$